# arraylist no suitable methods for list.add (array is of object type)

Tags: java, object, arraylist, compiler-errors

```
    public StudentLottery() {
     ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
}



    public void addStudents() {

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    String id;
    String name;
    Student s;
    System.out.println("Enter? (y or n):");
    input=keyboard.nextLine();
    while (!(input.equals("n"))){
        System.out.println("Name:");
        name=keyboard.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("ID:");
        id=keyboard.nextLine();
        s=new Student(name,id);
        if (!(list.contains(s)))
            list.add(s);//error
        System.out.println("Enter? (y or n):");
        input=keyboard.nextLine();
    }

}
```

error occurs on list.add(s), I thought arrayLists could accept any type of object, but this arraylist only likes strings, so I'm unsure what I should be doing to fix this, so that my arraylist will accept student objects

jcreator says no suitable add method found

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think this can be anything but Java.

Comment: @arshajii That was my guess as well, but I actually asked the question to stimulate the OP to update the question to include it as a tag. Maybe I should have been more explicit about that goal ;)

Answer (score 2):

The list you've declared in the `StudentLottery` constructor is a *local* variable, not a field. You can't access it beyond the scope of the constructor. Perhaps you meant:

```
private ArrayList<Student> list;  // i.e. list is a field

public StudentLottery() {
    this.list = new ArrayList<Student>();  // initialize list in constructor
}
```